# Creating new structure variables for each iteration in a loop

Tags: matlab, function, loops, structure

I have a function which assess a time series of data over a particular range within that time.

The output of the function is a structure array. The function is performed over a given range of time e.g 0 to 15 seconds. I would like to produce iterate this so that I can get the results for the each time interval. E.g structure 1 = 0 to 15 seconds; structure 2 = 15 to 30 seconds and so on.

So far this is what I have but I am unable to save/get the results for each iteration, on the last one (e.g 15 to 30):

```
for i = 1:2    
    while n<30
       y(i) = function(n n+15);    
       n=n+15;
    end
end
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear. You are trying to do two different things to the two sections? If so, why not use if statements? `if time < 15` then `foo` `else` `bar`

Comment: No I'm trying to get the output of the function for the range 0 to 15 and then for the range 15 to 30. However I am only able to save the latter so far.

Comment: It may be helpful http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/33750-save-loop-data Use an array.

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question and simplifying the description. The modulo operator is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array and simple if statement:

```
if mod(i, 15) == 0  
   do something
```

Every value can be stored separately in an array. Array index is being incremented in the if condition.